# No wallpaper at startup

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, desktop-background, lxde

I'm using lubuntu 14.04. The wallpaper fails to show at start up on the screen, only a black screen with the desktop icons. If I click on the Desktop 1 or Desktop 2 icons, the wallpaper will show. What is wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the desktop and select "Desktop preferences".

In the "Appearance" window you should see a checkbox marked "Use the same wallpaper on all desktops". Is the box checked?

Comment: Thanks. it doesn't make any difference if it's checked or not, the result is still no wallpaper until I click on Desktop 1 or 2